# Separate class for title and description in gallery

Tags: gallery, title, field-description

i want in gallery different size o font in titlle of image and different as well at decription/caption under title. Of course i would like change by css, but envira has just CSS for caption. It is changig both (titlle and description too).

I did try put hardcode to titlle in HTML, or CSS in div, but envira does not take it and still make the same code for titlle and description.

I did write to support of Envira Galllery, but they can not say if and when will repair the bug. I can not stay for one year and wait for it because my customer want it now.

Can someone help me with some trick?

Thank you for any advice or help.

Here is link to simple view on problem. You can see at first image, that title and description are toghether in one field.

https://patrikmolitor.cz/envira/fotogalerie/

I did try make own div with own class put to title and decsription gallery, like i did write above. Usually it is working but not in envira. The field of title and description is not recognize html.